# Convert character to CP1252 Hex in c#

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I wrote a function to convert a string to a hex string.  So "abc" would be converted to "616263".

Here is the function:

```
    private string StringToHex(string myString)
    {
        int ctr, li_max;
        string ls_hex = "";

        li_max = myString.Length;
        for(ctr = 0; ctr < li_max; ctr++)
            ls_hex = ls_hex + (Convert.ToInt16(myString[ctr])).ToString("x2");

        return ls_hex;
    }
```

However, when I have unicode characters like "‹abc" I get "2039616263".  So my first character is converted to 2039 (unicode). I wanted to get "8B616263" (CP1252).  See image below:

[image]

How can I get the hex value for the correct encoding?
ie: 8B instead of 2039

Comment: Once a string is encoded incorrectly you can't recover.  So whatever code read the byte[] array and converted to string must be fixed to use the correct encoding.  It probably is the code that read a file that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get use the CP1252 encoding to get the bytes of the string:

```
private string StringToHex(string myString)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(myString);
    return string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}
```

My output is

> 8B616263